# Decoding unicode string within a tuple

Tags: python, json, decode

I have the following set of simple examples of code, none of which are doing what I want:

```
import json

a = "u'Kolo Tour\xe9'"
print a

b = (a.decode('cp1252'), 1)
print b

c = (a, 1)
print c

d = ','.join((b.decode('cp1252')))
print d
```

The final example is throwing up an error about a tuple having no method for decoding. What I want my final item to look like is:

```
Kolo Touré,1
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and what the correct syntax I need to fix my issue is please?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

A segment of the actual source data I am attempting to parse in my full scale code prints like this to the screen in both command shell and python IDLE:

```
(u'Jos\xe9 Enrique', 14230, 29, 3, u'DL', 184, 76, True, False)
```

Comment: Why are you starting with a `unicode` literal represented in a string?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Because this is an example of how an item is represented within a tuple in a much larger piece of code I have. The issues begin when I try and decode the unicode item whilst it is part of a tuple. If I decode it before hand, putting it into a tuple seems to undo the decoding and doing it within the tuple throws up an error.

Comment: That sounds wrong. Please show your source data.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have posted a short segment of the real data I am working on as taking from the screen. I cant post my actual code as there is a lot of it.

Answer (score 1):

Printing a tuple displays the *representation* of the contents, so it is *extremely* unlikely that you have a `unicode` literal in a string.

```
newdata = (olddata[0], 1)
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your latest output:

```
u'{},1'.format(olddata[0])
```

but I'm wondering if you don't want to use `csv` instead for output generation.

Comment: do you understand my issue though? I need to join the items of the tuple together using a ','.join() statement, but this is causing me an error because the item within the tuple needs decoding.

Comment: So... your end result needs to be a string?

Comment: yes, and when I attempt the conversion I get an error that the item in question within the tuple could not be decoded,

Comment: Yeah... you're going to have to backtrack and figure out what you actually need. Your requirements are making no sense.

Comment: I have edited the post to show what I want my final output to look like. please review.

Comment: ok, nearly there, but '1' is a dynamic value...it is not a string or something static, so cannot be included within the formatting statement as you have done. also the final output should be "Kolo Touré,1", not "u'Kolo Touré',1". thanks.

Comment: For more dynamic values simply add more formatting specifiers. As for how you're getting that output, I'm unable to get anything similar to it given the input tuple you've posted.

Comment: ok, lets assume i have a tuple with two items in it: ("u'Kolo Tour\xe9'", '1'). this is part of a larger piece of code. the first element of the tuple will always be a name containing non ascii characters and the second element could be any number. i need to join the tuple together into a string using a ','.join() statement. this however causes an error because the non ascii characters cannot be encoded into a string. how can i get what i want? your answer is almost what i am after, but not quite...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you getting that broken tuple in the first place?

Comment: could we just focus on this simple example or it will get too complicated. how to i join a tuple into a string when the tuple contains not ascii characters? standard decoding does not seem to work.